# How to make a h1 tag in html touch the edges of the screen?

Tags: html, css

I just started learning HTML and just created this static:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/classes.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/ids.css">
        <title>Total Devastation</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1 class="header-main">Total Devastation</h1>
        <div id="mainmenu">
            <ul>
                <li>
                <a href="">Hello!</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                <a href="">How</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                <a href="">Are</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                <a href="">You</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="body-main">
            <p>
            Hi there! Welcome to this newly created static RPG.
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to make the h1 container (class header-main) touches the edges of the screen like it touched the right-side here

And here is the css part:

```
body {
    background:#aaa;
}

.header-main {
    background:#555;
    font-family:calibri;
    font-size:32pt;
    color:#eee;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:0;
    padding:10px;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Use the Css reset code in your html... It overwrites the default css broswer style ... Here is the link for reset code http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 2):

By default body will have margin of 8px set it 0..so your h1 container touches the screen

**Css**

```
body{
background:#aaa;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

if you want h1 to touch the top of browser... set the h1 margin to 0

```
.header-main {
    background:#555;
    font-family:calibri;
    font-size:32pt;
    color:#eee;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0;       /*changes done */
    padding:10px;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make margin, padding to 0 in html,body tags

```
html, body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/q42kxd7p/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
body {
  background: #aaa;
  margin: 0;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
.header-main {
  background: #555;
  font-family: calibri;
  font-size: 32pt;
  color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <h1 class="header-main">Total Devastation</h1>
<div id="mainmenu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="">Hello!</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="">How</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="">Are</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="">You</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="body-main">
  <p>
    Hi there! Welcome to this newly created static RPG.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is simple, your browser automaticly adds 8px margin to the entire document, so when you remove this from your html by the following CSS:

```
html{
margin: 0;
}
```

Your problem should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this css:

```
 body{
    margin:0
}
 h1{
    margin:0    
}
```

Because of the default css of browser.

Answer (score -1):

```
    .header-main {
    background:#555;
    font-family:calibri;
    font-size:32pt;
    color:#eee;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:0;
    padding:10px;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    top:0;

}
```